# Does Google expose API for Find My Device service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-api, google-location-services

Does Google expose API for Find My Device service?
I would like to build a NodeJS backend to extract the location of my friends` phone using Google Find My Device service (using their gmail email).
Of course, they need to approve sharing their location first.
If these API are exposed, what is the process and how the authentiction works in this case.

GCP support recommended posting my question to the developer community on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API for googles Find my device feature.

This is a featue they offer themselves I don't think this is one they will want to share with developers.